# How to track detected object by applying SVM?

Tags: c++, opencv, svm

I have successfully trained SVM to predict object, but I am not understanding how to detect or track the object from an image or a video, which contains the object. I am just able to know which class the given image belongs to by svm.predict(&Mat) which gives me only a label number. Can anybody give me any idea or any links?
Thanks in advance.
using the following lines, I trained SVM.

```
CvSVM SVM;
SVM.train(trainme,labels);
SVM.save("classifier.xml");
```

By the following line, I am predicting the trained classifier.

```
Mat tryme(0, dictionarySize, CV_32FC1);
Mat tryDescriptor;
Mat test = imread("image_path/image.jpg", 0);   
vector<KeyPoint> keypoints3;
features.detect(test, keypoints3);
bowDE.compute(test, keypoints3, tryDescriptor);
tryme.push_back(tryDescriptor);
cout<<SVM.predict(tryme)<<endl;
```

In returns, it is giving label number which refers the class where it belongs to.

Comment: Your question is quite unclear... try to re formulate and give a minimal example of the code you have now. Also try to be more clear about what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Thank you for you reply. I have edited now. Hopefully, now it would be more clear than before.

Comment: It is better now! What you need to achieve? The output from the classifier is correct, il tells you which class of objects is recognized in that image...

Comment: Yes, and my target is to detect and track the object from an image.